# Perform xgboost prediction with pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, prediction, xgboost

I have a dataset with prediction input dataset which consists of some generic columns, some feature columns and a label column. I also have an xgboost model of type xgb.Booster. How can I perform prediction on the input dataset using the xgb model? This is the code I have right now

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, DataFrame, udf, array
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType

feature_cols = ["feature1", "feature2", "feature3"]
label_col = "label"
all_cols = ["id1", "id2"] + feature_cols + label_col
pred_col_name = "pred"
prediction_path = "/input/path"

prediction_input = spark.read.parquet(prediction_path).select(all_cols)

for column in feature_cols:
    prediction_input = prediction_input.withColumn(column, col(column).cast("float"))

def predict_udf(*features):
    dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(list(features))
    return float(model.predict(dmatrix)[0])

predict_udf_spark = udf(predict_udf, FloatType())

mask_labeled = prediction_input.filter(col(label_col) != 0)

if mask_labeled.count() > 0:
    prediction_labeled = mask_labeled.withColumn(pred_col_name, predict_udf_spark(*[mask_labeled[col] for col in feature_cols]))
    prediction_labeled.select(*output_cols).repartition(1000).write.csv(output_path, header=False, mode="append")
```

But this code is giving me the following error

```
jc = sc._jvm.functions.array(_to_seq(sc, cols, _to_java_column))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you are trying to use the `xgboost` algorithm of the [xgboost library](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) in a `spark` context. Please note that there is a dedicated `spark` implementation within the `xgboost` library, which your code does not seem to use (from your `predict_udf` function I understand that you are trying to wrangle your `pyspark` data, perform predictions, and convert the predictions back into a `pyspark` format). You can make your code a lot easier by using the `SparkXGBClassifier` to fit your model and apply the predictions.

Below you can find a fully reproducible example showing how you can fit the [`SparkXGBClassifier`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/spark_estimator.html#sparkxgbclassifier) and use its predictions, where the code was written in `pyspark==3.5.0`, `xgboost=2.0.0`, and `python==3.10.12` using `Google Colab`. Please note that my example kept the machine learning part to an absolute minimum and does not show how you should train a machine learning model (e.g. there is literally no model evaluation, hyperparameter tuning, validation, etc.)

Please note that since you haven't provided any example data or information about dependencies, it is very difficult to replicate your problem. Having used the data from my `SparkXGBClassifier` example, I get an error from this function:

```
def predict_udf(*features):
    dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(list(features))
    return float(model.predict(dmatrix)[0])
```

which gives me the error:

```
ValueError: Please reshape the input data into 2-dimensional matrix.
```

**Reproducible example of how to train a `SparkXGBClassifier` on data which (presumably) resembles yours:**

```
# required for Google Colab 
# !pip install pyspark

import random

from xgboost.spark import SparkXGBClassifier
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('spark_session').getOrCreate()

dataset_size = 100_000
labels = [0, 1, 2]

feature_cols = ["feature1", "feature2", "feature3"]
label_col = "label"
pred_col_name = "pred"
all_cols = ["id1", "id2"] + feature_cols + [label_col]

data = [
    (i+1, i+1001, random.random(), random.random() * 1_000, random.random() * 1_000, random.choice(labels))
    for i in range(dataset_size)
]

prediction_input = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("id1", "id2", "feature1", "feature2", "feature3", 'label'))

# VectorAssembler required if you cannot train on GPU
vec_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=feature_cols, outputCol="features")
prediction_input = vec_assembler.transform(prediction_input)


prediction_input.show(5)

# +---+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+--------------------+
# |id1| id2|           feature1|         feature2|          feature3|label|            features|
# +---+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+--------------------+
# |  1|1001| 0.5020143404453867|317.9123523833789| 80.99056175390396|    1|[0.50201434044538...|
# |  2|1002| 0.5070869997709387|760.0823371718348| 939.3547071386726|    0|[0.50708699977093...|
# |  3|1003| 0.4075714302471459|196.3132088899051| 618.1676550139244|    2|[0.40757143024714...|
# |  4|1004| 0.2969972133808245|708.3811336815659| 633.2752459199171|    0|[0.29699721338082...|
# |  5|1005|0.18151957704419186|307.2738259905281|416.45499440549196|    2|[0.18151957704419...|
# +---+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+--------------------+

# create a xgboost pyspark regressor estimator and set device="cuda"
classifier = SparkXGBClassifier(
  features_col='features',
  label_col=label_col
)

# train and return the model
model = classifier.fit(prediction_input)

# predict on test data
predict_df = model.transform(prediction_input)
predict_df.show(5)

# +---+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+
# |id1| id2|           feature1|         feature2|          feature3|label|            features|       rawPrediction|prediction|         probability|
# +---+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+
# |  1|1001| 0.5020143404453867|317.9123523833789| 80.99056175390396|    1|[0.50201434044538...|[0.45034444332122...|       2.0|[0.33440056443214...|
# |  2|1002| 0.5070869997709387|760.0823371718348| 939.3547071386726|    0|[0.50708699977093...|[0.59553760290145...|       0.0|[0.35163819789886...|
# |  3|1003| 0.4075714302471459|196.3132088899051| 618.1676550139244|    2|[0.40757143024714...|[0.48832395672798...|       2.0|[0.33687391877174...|
# |  4|1004| 0.2969972133808245|708.3811336815659| 633.2752459199171|    0|[0.29699721338082...|[0.60149568319320...|       0.0|[0.35905247926712...|
# |  5|1005|0.18151957704419186|307.2738259905281|416.45499440549196|    2|[0.18151957704419...|[0.26893869042396...|       2.0|[0.27391168475151...|
# +---+----+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+
```